# Issue while executing simple PS script

Tags: powershell

PS C:> c:\test.ps1

```
Error:
*The term 'c:\test.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a
 spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify t
At line:1 char:12
+ c:\test.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\test.ps1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException*
```

My Script contains

```
$letterArray = "a","b","c","d"
foreach ($letter in $letterArray)
{
   Write-Host $letter
}
```

Comment: Your script is absolutely fine - are you sure that it (1) exists in the location you specified `c:\test.ps1` and (b) the user account you are running PowerShell as is able to read form that location?

Answer (score 0):

Move the script to another(deeper) folder and try again? You can also try

```
& c:\test.ps1
```